# Getting variable from database and putting to image link

Tags: php, variables

```
<?php
  if($skin > 0 && $skin < 100)
  {
    $imagename = "www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/pcp/Skins/Skin_0".$skin.".png";
  }
  else
  {
    $imagename = "www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/pcp/Skins/Skin_".$skin.".png";
  }
  echo '<img src='.$imagename.' class="floatRight">';
?>
```

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work, I viewed the source code and this appaered:

"www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/pcp/Skins/Skin_.png class="floatRight">"

Comment: echo '<img src="'.$imagename.'" class="floatRight">';

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes:

```
echo "<img src='$imagename' class='floatRight'>";
```

read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/2460773) on the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP.

Comment: IT does not solve the issue unless you add the single quotes around `$imagename` as well like around `floatRight`.

Answer (score 0):

image link add http:// prefix

```
$imagename = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/pcp/Skins/Skin_".$skin.".png";
```

or

don't write domain name

```
$imagename = "/pcp/Skins/Skin_".$skin.".png";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this:

```
"www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/pcp/Skins/Skin_.png class="floatRight">"
```

in your source code
then i guess the problem is with `$skin` variable please check is this an array or not if so then use `$skin[index]`.

here:

```
$imagename = "www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/pcp/Skins/Skin_0".$skin.".png";
```

Answer (score 0):

use like :-

```
echo '<img src="'.$imagename.'" class="floatRight">';
```

this may help you.